# How to Concatenate All Worksheets of a Workbook In Excel

Tags: c#, excel, merge, office-interop

I must first say that I am not really familiar with VBA or macros in general.

I have an Excel file that contains separate worksheets for some "Base Items".

Each worksheet contains a relationship between a product and an accessory.  The number, if 0, means its incompatible, and any number > 0, is the number of accessories that can go with the product.

Each worksheet contains different accessories and codes, but some duplicates may arise.

An example of the data:

```
|            | J0021       | J0022        |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| Product 1  |     1       |      1       |
| Product 2  |     1       |      2       |
| Product 3  |     1       |      1       |
| Product 4  |     0       |      0       |
| Product 5  |     0       |      1       |
| Product 6  |     1       |      0       |
```

There are 43 separate worksheets, and anywhere from 500 to 2000 cells denoting the relationship.

I was thinking of just having a one-to-one table that denoted the relationship in the following manner:

```
Table Name: ProductAccessoryCompat

 Id (Primary Key)   | ProductId (Foreign Key) | AccessoryId(Foreign Key) | Count
 -------------------|-------------------------|--------------------------|------
 LB1 (ProdBase+Num) |         Product 1       |  J0021                   |   1  
 LB2                |         Product 1       |  J0022                   |   1  
 FV1                |         Product 2       |  J0021                   |   1  
 FV2                |         Product 2       |  J0022                   |   2  
 BG1                |         Product 3       |  J0021                   |   1  
 BG2                |         Product 3       |  J0022                   |   1  
 HG1                |         Product 4       |  J0021                   |   0  
 HG2                |         Product 4       |  J0022                   |   0  
 JJ1                |         Product 5       |  J0021                   |   0  
 JJ2                |         Product 5       |  J0022                   |   1  
 JL1                |         Product 6       |  J0021                   |   1  
 JL2                |         Product 6       |  J0022                   |   0
```

The worksheets have the same kind of data, but will have different columns of products and different rows.

I know I need to concatenate all of them into a single worksheet, and then export it as a CSV, and then import that CSV into MySQL.

Could anyone help me determine how to concatenate the different worksheets into a single one in the format that I've described for the table I'd like to create?

I figured it would be something like the following naive pseudo-code:

```
var NumOfSheets = Workbook.Worksheets.Count;
var newSheet = Workbook.CreateSheet();
for (i = 0; i < NumOfSheets; i++)
{
    var curSheet = Workbook.GetSheet(i);
    curSheet.Activate;

    var numColumns = curSheet.Columns.Count;
    var numRows = curSheet.Rows.Count;
    var relationships = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    for (j = 0; j < numRows; j++)
    {
        var currentProd = curSheet.getCell(j, 0);

        for(k = 0; k < numColumns; j++)
        {
            var currentAcc = curSheet.getCell(0, k);
            var relationship = curSheet.getCell(j, k);
            if (relationship != 0) var relationships[currentProd][currentAcc] = relationship;
        }
    }
}

[Then iterate through the 2D associative array, inserting
 a new row for each product, and a new column for each
 accessory that each do net yet exist on the spreadsheet.]
```

I'm almost thinking it would be easier to do by hand, but you know, laziness wins.

Edit:  I just realized that I could probably just ignore the 0 columns, so I added that to the pseudo-code.

Comment: Ahh - that's so close.  That's essentially what I'm looking for, but both of those assume that the headers are consistent throughout the worksheets.  The headers aren't exactly the same throughout each of the worksheets.  They're the titles of the accessories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of messing around with VBA, I decided that I did not want to go that route, and fired up Visual Studio to write my solution using C#.

A friend of mine noted that I could open and read Excel files with SQL syntax using ADO.NET.

I did this, and things worked out well, until it came time to rewrite my massaged data into a new worksheet.

There is a bug with using ADO.NET and writing into Excel that causes strings written into cells to have a an apostrophe prepended to them. (E.g. "'derp" instead of "derp").

You can find information on that [at this Microsoft link: How To Use ADO with Excel Data from Visual Basic or VBA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819)

I ended up using the Office Interop classes, which I found information about here:

[How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084)

I'm going to post my really naive attempt.  Although it was successful and performed the exact function that I needed, someone might be able to look over this and pluck something useful out later.

*Note!  This is just a one-off thing for me - I didn't intend on reusing this code, so it's awful.  Sorry.

Without further ado:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsolidateAccProdExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sheetPath = @"PATH-TO-FILE";
            string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"",sheetPath);

            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> relationshipDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

            using (OleDbConnection oleConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                oleConnection.Open();
                System.Data.DataTable dt = oleConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                List<DataTable> listDt = new List<DataTable>();

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    listDt.Add(GetWorksheetData(oleConnection, (string)dt.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"]));
                }

                List<DataRow> rowList = new List<DataRow>();

                for (int i = 0; i < listDt.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataColumnCollection dtColumns = listDt[i].Columns;
                    foreach (DataRow drRow in listDt[i].Rows)
                    {
                        if (!(drRow.ItemArray[0] is DBNull))
                        {
                            Dictionary<string, string> accessoryData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                            string rowName = (string)drRow.ItemArray[0];
                            for (int j = 1; j < drRow.ItemArray.Length; j++)
                            {
                                if ((string)drRow.ItemArray[j].ToString() != 0.ToString()) accessoryData.Add(dtColumns[j].ColumnName, (string)drRow.ItemArray[j].ToString());
                            }
                            try { relationshipDictionary.Add(rowName, accessoryData); }
                            catch (ArgumentException e) { Trace.WriteLine("problem: " + rowName); }
                        }
                    }
                }

                writeConcatenatedSheets(relationshipDictionary, oleConnection);
            }

            long relationshipsCount = 0;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> product in relationshipDictionary)
            {
                relationshipsCount += product.Value.Count;
            }
            Trace.WriteLine(relationshipsCount);

        }

        private static void writeConcatenatedSheets(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> relationshipDictionary, OleDbConnection connection)
        {
            int relationshipsCount = 0;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> product in relationshipDictionary)
            {
                relationshipsCount += product.Value.Count;
            }

            int currentCount = 1;
            string writeCommand = "";

            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = true;

            Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(@"PATH-TO-FILE");
            Excel.Sheets excelSheets = workbook.Worksheets;

            Excel.Worksheet consolidateSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item("Consolidated Data");

            Excel.Range rows = consolidateSheet.Rows;

            int count = rows.Count;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> product in relationshipDictionary)
            {
                int productCount = 0;
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> accessory in product.Value)
                {
                    string[,] values = new string[1,4];
                    values[0,0] = product.Key + "_[" + productCount + "]";
                    values[0,1] = product.Key;
                    values[0,2] = accessory.Key;
                    values[0,3] = accessory.Value;

                    rows.get_Range("A" + currentCount, "D" + currentCount).Value2 = values;

                    ++productCount;
                    ++currentCount;
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }

        private static DataTable GetWorksheetData(OleDbConnection oleConnection, string SheetName)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OleDbDataAdapter odba = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format ("SELECT * FROM [{0}]",SheetName), oleConnection);
            odba.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```